# Python loops with rpy and psycopg2

Tags: python, r, for-loop

Good day,

I've been struggling some time now and cannot find an answer on Google.  Im using Python with rpy (not rpy2) and psycopg2 for PostgreSQL.  When trying a loop for SQL I would do the following:

```
for i in xrange(1:11):
    script = "DELETE FROM table WHERE column = %d" % i
    cur.execute(script)
```

This works fine, but how can I do something similar with rpy?  For example the following:

```
for i in xrange(1:11):
    test = "15 * %d" % i
    r('test')                # This does not work
    r.assign('test', test')
    r('print(test)')         # This does not work either
    x = r('test')
    print x                  # This prints 15 * 1, then 15 * 2, but not 15 and 30.
```

Sorry if this is too simple, but I'm stuck!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out!

Simply:

```
r('test <- 15 * %d' % i)
```

This never worked before as I did this:

```
r('test <- 15 * %d') % i
```

Not sure why this makes a difference, but this seems to work!